How do I get a locale or timezone used on Venus?
In this answer, Stéphane Chazelas uses a UVC timezone and vs_VS locale. When I asked about them, the reply was that these are the timezone and locale used on ... Venus. I'm not entirely sure whether the response was tongue-in-cheek, and it might well be something bespoke. But I'm interested in trying out these settings, so I how can I do that on Arch Linux or a recent Ubuntu release, without having a friend from Venus?

Venus, the planet, doesn't have timezones. Timezones are an Earth-human idea, based on Earth's Prime Meridian, and the needs of railroads.

That's what I would think, but then people use Klingon actively ¯\(ツ)/¯ so who knows if someone came up with one as a joke or for testing naive assumptions about locales and time.

Venus, Florida? UTC-4h?

On Earth, timezones can generally be handled by consulting a table of locations and their current and past (and known-future, if applicable) timezone offsets. That results in some offset that allows conversion between local and UTC time, but the clock/calendar system itself won't change. On different planets, the lengths of local years and days will be different from Earths, and the concept of a month might be very different or even not applicable at all (multiple moons / no moon), so it's not just a different table of offsets, but an entirely different conversion formula for each planet.

@telcoM not to mention accounting for gravity, an important consideration in the plans for a lunar timezone

That said, I think there are no timezones defined for other planets, since there has not yet been any significant need to coordinate actions on other planets/moons using a timescale that is reasonably synchronized to the local day/night cycle. Mars rover mission planners may use "local Mars time" at the rover they're interested in because daylight is an issue, but for synchronizing communications, something like Mission Elapsed Time or Earth UTC time is generally a better choice. If you need accuracy you'll also need the Theory of Relativity on interplanetary distances and different gravity...

The question concerns the non-quoting, double-quoting, and single-quoting of a command substitution.
The point made in that answer is that without double-quoting the command substitution $(date) or `date`, the result of the expansion will undergo word splitting and filename globbing.
The made-up timezone UVC highlights that you can't depend on what date outputs and that you can't rely on the date output to not contain filename globbing characters. There is nothing stopping anyone from creating their own time zone, and double-quoting the command substitution, or expansions in general, is a sane defensive programming habit.
I'm assuming that the date utility is only used in that question as an example of a command that outputs some dynamic text.
